# Is there a way to create a list of all columns in spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataSet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ08K.png)

I need to get a list of all values for every first column value (in this case there are only two ,1 and 2).

I tried to groupBy the first column and I want to aggregate by all columns. this what I get when I aggregate by the second column using this code:

```
df.groupBy("_c0").agg(collect_list("_c1")).show():
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VURQ.png)

The Idea is to get all values in the other columns in one list for each first column value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
scala> val df = List((1,2,3,4),(1,5,6,7),(2,8,9,10),(2,11,12,13)).toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.show
+---+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3| _4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|
|  1|  5|  6|  7|
|  2|  8|  9| 10|
|  2| 11| 12| 13|
+---+---+---+---+


scala> val firstColName = "_1"
firstColName: String = _1

scala> df.groupBy(firstColName).agg(flatten(collect_list(array(df.columns.filterNot(c=>c.equals(firstColName)).map(c=>col(c)):_*))).as("otherCols")).show(false)
+---+----------------------+
|_1 |otherCols             |
+---+----------------------+
|1  |[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]    |
|2  |[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]|
+---+----------------------+
```